# How to filter out auto-reply email by program

Tags: email

I have written a program to send emails to some recipients. After sending emails, some auto-reply emails will be returned. For example (no such recipients, mailbox is full, out of office etc).

Is there any information in the email (e.g. header) such that my program can filter out those auto-reply message?

Or any other mechanisums can be used to perform this task?

It is because my program only wants to get those actual-reply-by-recipients email, instead of auto-reply email.

Thanks.

Comment: I could be more help if you post your code and what type of email system you are using. php? PHP Mailer? Or another language?

Comment: Thanks. I am using PHP to send and get email.

Answer (score 0):

Just setup a rule in the outgoing email account to move all received email to the trash? Assuming that you have an email box for the auto emails only.

Comment: But how to distiguish those actual-reply emails with those auto-reply emails?

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you have an account that is sending emails, and those email are being returned by some people. In you email account, you can just setup a "Rule" that it will delete any email incoming, or you can even do it so that it will delete all incoming if it has a specific text in the subject. What kind of email account are you using?

Comment: I am using gmail account.

Comment: This article has what you need. Please read it: http://fieldguide.gizmodo.com/7-gmail-filters-to-make-email-less-of-a-chore-1646551691 You will need to learn the filters and set it up so that any email with a certain subject is fikltered into the trash. You should be able to figure it out from here.

Comment: But how to filter out those auto reply email?